# Replace all invisible controll characters and separators except whitespace

Tags: java, string

I try to cleanup incoming Strings (invisible controll characters and separators except whitespace) but I can't clean them all. Still get some uncleaned ones. I am using following [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) expression:

```
String cleanedPart = codePart.trim().replaceAll("[\\p{Zl}\\p{Zp}\\p{C}]+", "");
```

I also have a simple junit test:

```
assertEquals("one.two.thr%ee.fou rrr.bla", Cleaner.cleanupString(" one. two . thr%ee\n\t\r .fou rrr \t.bla "));
    assertEquals("one...two.thr%ee....", Cleaner.cleanupString(" one...two. thr%ee\n\t\r . ... "));
    assertEquals("one...two.thr%ee....", Cleaner.cleanupString("one\r...two.thr%ee.... "));
    assertEquals("onetwo", Cleaner.cleanupString("one\rtwo"));

    assertEquals("...one.two.three..four...", Cleaner.cleanupString("...one.two.three..four..."));
```

But in my live system I get still some Strings with a "CR" like in line 1 and 3:
[image]

Anybody here has an idea?

Comment: Btw. are you aware that `CR == \r` and `LF == \n`?

Answer (score 3):

The classes you use are as far as i can see not defined: [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

What about this regex:

```
// replace all control characters unless they are `\n\t\r`
// space is not a control character
.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\n\t\r]]", "");
```

and maybe even more strict.

```
// keeping only newline, carriage return, space, tab, and non-whitespace characters:
.replaceAll("[^\\S \n\r\t]", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Well Absurd-Mind's `.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\n\t\r]]", "");` and my `.replaceAll("[\\p{Zl}\\p{Zp}\\p{C}]+", "");` solutions work correct and Strings get cleaned. It was an export issues somewhere else in my code!